# CRM 4.0 sdk dll is not working with Windows Mobile 6.5.3 Project

Tags: visual-studio-2008, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-4, windows-mobile-6.5

I'm working with a project right now using a device with a **Windows Mobile 6.5.3** in it. In my **Visual Studio 2008** Project i'm trying to make use of **CRM 4.0 sdk dll** so I could call the **CRM services**. The problem now is that **microsoft.crm.sdktypeproxy.dll** or **microsoft.crm.sdk.dll** is having conflict with the other assemblies that's why I cannot build or run my project. My target framework is .Net 3.5

**Error Message:**

1. Error   1   The type
   'System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol' is defined in
   an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to
   assembly 'System.Web.Services, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

**Main Issue:**

1. Crm dll have conflict with other assemblies in the windows mobile
   6.5.3 project
2. Cannot build the project because of the error.

**Solution I Tried:**

1. Remove and Add System.Web.Service v4.0
2. Remove System.Web.Service v4.0 and add System.Web.Service v2.0
3. Make a new project with target framework .Net 2.0
4. Tried googling it but I haven't found any article related to this one.

**Note:**
 1. Where using these dll because our CRM setup does not allow us to
        login in the crm using passport authentication.
 2. Since our windows mobile device is not able to login to crm using
    windows authentication. I need to find a way to call the CRM service
        using the dll.

Comment: Possibly you or the included reference is referencing a Full Framework assembly. If so, you can not fix that without source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion in this situation is always to create a C# Web Service that will act as a bridge between CRM and your Windows Mobile application.

The Web Service use .NET so you can easily connect to CRM, and because is a Web Service you can consume it by any platform (including Windows Mobile)

Comment: Your right. I gave up debugging the crm dll and created my own web service that will call the crm service. Although it would be nice if we can resolve this issue for future reference.